# React-cookie ломает вёрстку компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookie, next.js

Я начинающий в изучении react/next и сейчас пробую написать проект с фронтедом на базе next.js/ts. Возникает проблема с авторизацией, которую я пытаюсь сделать сам, без специальной библиотеки, потому что маршрут /api занял бэкендом. Я хочу при отправке запроса авторизации по логину и паролю записывать полученные username и auth-key в куки, чтобы в дальнейшем шапка сразу рендерилась с юзернеймом пользователя, если куки есть. Когда я устанавливаю дефолтное значение для моего контекста авторизации из куки, происходит странное поведение компонента бутстрапа, ButtonGroup. Он как бы заменяется при рендеринге на NavbarCollapse, это отдельный компонент который стоит после него, и не связан. Получается что NavbarCollapse дублируется и кнопки (Обычная с username и dropdown) попадают в него а не в ButtonGroup. Причём если я значением username ставлю простую хардкод-строку, это отрабатывает нормально, а вот если беру из куки - всё ломается, хотя это абсолютно такая же строка, и ничего больше.

Чтобы лучше понять: вот что сейчас - https://radikal.ru/big/fsl1pz269smjc , вот как должно быть - https://radikal.ru/big/pzcmkvs5sj6wj

Вот код компонента Auth:

```
const Auth:FC<IAuthProps> = (props) => {
const {children, cookies} = props;
const cookieUsername = cookies.get('username');
const [username, setUsername] = useState(cookieUsername);

return (
   <AuthProvider username={username} >
     {children}
   </AuthProvider>
)
```

AuthProvider:

```
const AuthContext = createContext<authContextType>(authContextDefaultValues); 
export function useAuth() { return useContext(AuthContext); } 
export const AuthProvider: FC<authContextType> = (props) => { 
const {username,children} = props;

const value = {
    username 
}

return (
    <>
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    </>
); }
```

И компонент Header:

```
const Header:FC<headerProps> = ({showSignin}:headerProps) => {
const { username } = useAuth();
return (
<header className="position-fixed w-100">
    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" className={styles.navbar_desktop} expand="sm">
        <Navbar.Brand href="#" className={styles.logo}><img src="/images/icon/logo.svg" 
        className={styles.logoImg}
        alt="Логотип"/>
        </Navbar.Brand>
        {username && <ButtonGroup>
            <DropdownButton as={ButtonGroup} title="Dropdown" variant="success" id="bg-dropdown-1">
                <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1">Profile</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item eventKey="2">Orders</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item eventKey="3">Logout</Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>
            <Button variant="light">
                <img id={styles.userIcon} src="/images/icons/user.png" alt="Пользователь"/>
                <span className="mx-2">{username}</span>
            </Button>
        </ButtonGroup>}
        {!username && <Button className={styles.signinButton + " py-2 px-4"} onClick={showSignin} 
            variant="success">Login</Button>}
        <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav className="mr-auto w-100 d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-around">
                <Nav.Link className={styles.navlink_desktop} href="/about">О магазине</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="/#contact">Контакты</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            <Form className="me-3">
                <InputGroup className={styles.searchField_desktop}>
                    <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="What you want to find?" />
                    <Button variant="success" type="submit">
                        <img className={styles.searchIcon} alt="Search" src="/images/icons/search.svg" />
                    </Button>
                </InputGroup>
            </Form>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
        <a href="#" className={styles.cart_desktop}>
            <img className={styles.cartIcon} alt="Cart" src="/images/icons/cart.svg" />
            <Badge className={styles.badge} bg="secondary">0</Badge>
        </a>
    </Navbar>
</header>
)
```

Может ещё будет полезен обработчик данных формы входа, где я получаю и устанавливаю куки:

```
const handleSigninSubmit = (e:FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
e.preventDefault();

if(!cookies["auth-token"]) {
    axios.post(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ROOT + "/user/login", {
        username: login,
        password: password
    })
    .then(function (response:any) {
        setCookie("auth-token", response.data.data.auth_key, { path: "/", maxAge: 259200 });
        setCookie("username", response.data.data.username, { path: "/", maxAge: 259200 });
        setLogin('');
        setPassword('');
        props.handleClose();
    })
    .catch(function (error:any) {
    console.log(error)
    });
}}
```

Если кто-то знает, почему так происходит и как исправить, пожалуйста, объясните мне.

Comment: сделайте пример в сандбоксе

Comment: вот, тут без апи, простое куки. после входа надо перезагрузить страницу (потом доработаю). 
https://codesandbox.io/s/kx3te

Comment: проблема в том, что на стороне сервера не получает куков, поэтому GroupButton не рендерится (т.е. идет различие рендеринга на стороне сервера и клиента)

Comment: Спаибо за подсказку. Долго искал, что можно придумать, пока есть такая идея: При авторизации и получении данных так же положить в куки auth-token на клиенте (хоть это и не лучшее решение), а при инициализации приложения делать запрос на апи с заголовком, содержащим токен, получать данные по пользователю и отрисовывать его уже с контекстом пользователя. Переписал код опираясь на эту статью - https://jools.dev/server-side-auth-with-nextjs-context-and-hooks, с методом getInitialProps прямо в _app.tsx, но вижу что запрос на апи просто не идёт в этом методе.

Comment: Новый sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/applecart-next-o9u4v линк на апи заменил, запрос не пройдёт. Но почему он даже не вызывается? В сам метод точно попадает, и куку он наверняка цепляет, а axios-запроса нет. В общем, есть ли способ реализовать взаимодействие приложения с бэкендом без маршрута /api и серверных кук? у меня там php, который эти куки сохранять не будет. или без вариантов, менять путь к бэку, чтоб /api был доступен нексту?

Comment: В getInitialProps можно получать куки с контекста "context.req.cookies.get('username')"

Comment: вот я же и говорю дело не в куки в первую очередь. а в том что запрос внутри getInitialPops (и внутри функции getUser) не уходит. это от куки не зависит, я убирал её оттуда, заменял рандомной строкой и изменений нет. А вот при проверке getUser отдельно от getInitialProps там отрабатывает всё, и кука достатётся и запрос исполняется.

Comment: зашел, попробовал - запрос уходит и возвращается с ошибкой, т.к. сервер не доступен. Все работает

Comment: запрос и правда работает, а дело всё-таки в куки, не могу никак её получить. тем способом что описали вы, это сделать не получается потому как беру в getInitialProps контекст appContext.ctx и далее .req.headers уже пусто, куки там нет, ведь они установлены на клиенте а не на сервере.

Comment: appContext.ctx.req.cookies

Comment: нет этого там. как я уже понял getInitialProps работает только на сервере. Соответсвенно мои клиентские куки он никак не получит. А на клиенте после после входа пользователя я пока не понимаю, можно ли установить куку для сервера? скорее всего тоже никак, так как это разные вещи.. придётся менять структуру проекта

Comment: 1. Куки на сервер передаются с запросами
2. Иcпользуйте getServerSideProps вместо getInitialProps - так будет выполнятся только на сервере
3. appContext.ctx.req.cookies (в методе getInitialProps) - содержит куки

Comment: 1 и 3. Куки в контексте точно нет. Всё что есть в ctx - на скрине https://ibb.co/P9DkYgC
2. В App допускается только getInitialProps, getServerSideProps мне даёт ошибку.

Comment: не знаю что Вы делаете, но вот добавил одну строчку в Ваш код (форкнул) и свой адресс для получения токена. Вот результат после логина - https://ibb.co/NWBG4NQ

Comment: вы получаете токен с апи на js? подозреваю дело тут в том, что codesandbox, и возможно ваш апи оперируют им, у меня же это php, который видит только содержимое моего сформированного запроса, не больше и просто отдаёт ответ. в любом случае спасибо, что попытались помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Куки на сервере не достать потому, что я экспортирую приложение как статический сайт и устанавливаю их во время логина только в браузере. Самое простое решение - использовать хук useEffect в AuthProvider:

```
export const AuthProvider = (props:any) => {
const [auth, setAuth] = useState({ status: 'SIGNED_OUT', username: null });
const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(["auth-token"]);

useEffect(() => {
    const authToken = cookies["auth-token"];
    if(authToken) {
        getUser(authToken)
            .then((res) => {
                setAuth(res);
            })
    }
}, [])

const signin = async (login:string, password:string) => {
    return axios.post(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ROOT + "/user/login", {
        username: login,
        password: password
    })
        .then((response) => {
            setCookie("auth-token", response.data.data.auth_key, { path: "/", maxAge: 86400});
            setAuth({status: "SIGNED_IN", username: response.data.data.username});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Incorrect email or password entered.');
        });
};
return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth, signin }} {...props}                      />;
```

};

Но простое совсем не значит хорошее, хранить токены доступа на клиенте небезопасно, потому что они могут быть легко перехвачены CSRF-атакой